# How do you restore bootable flag to windows partition?

Tags: boot, uefi

On my Dell Inspiron 660 i have windows 8.1. Now, Feeling as if that is not open-source enough, i often boot into ubuntu 12.04 Via live usb. Doing so has, somehow, turned off bootable flag for windows partition when in legacy mode. Upon booting i get a `No bootable device -- insert boot disk and press any key` error. Windows works fine and I can boot it in UEFI mode. Very confused, but still an advanced user. Please help.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "bootable flag" on GPT disks, although `parted` confusingly identifies the [EFI System Partition (ESP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) as having its "boot flag" set. To diagnose your problem, I recommend you run the [Boot Info Script.](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) Upload the `RESULTS.txt` file that it generates to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) and post the URL to your document here.

Answer (score 0):

Your main Windows boot manager file (`EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi` on the ESP) doesn't seem to be present. Either Boot Info Script has failed to report it (as sometimes happens) or something's deleted it. If the latter, you should be able to restore it by running a Windows repair utility. Doing that is, however, a Windows issue, not an Ubuntu one, so you should ask about that on a Windows forum.

Note that Windows can boot from any given disk in only one of two modes (BIOS/CSM/legacy or EFI/UEFI); it can't switch back and forth willy-nilly. Your disk is set up for EFI/UEFI booting, so you will have no luck booting Windows in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode. If you were trying to do that, forget it and stick to EFI-mode booting.

Comment: The same windows install used to boot EFI as well as GPT, that's why I was asking. As stated, it boots into efi fine, but not into GPT any longer.

Comment: EFI is a type of firmware. GPT is a disk partitioning system. Windows boots in EFI mode *only* from GPT disks. Thus, your statement that "...it boots into efi fine, but not into GPT any longer..." makes little sense, unless perhaps you mean you can access the firmware setup utility but not boot the computer. Based on my answer, I suspect you once had a link to Boot Info Script or Boot Repair output, but that's gone now, so I can't re-review your setup.

Comment: Okay, I used to be able to boot EFI or legacy, happy?